# Cant return view but only recyclerview in onCreateView method (Fragment)

Tags: android

I plan to add a floating button in new feed function. However, during onCreateView method it only allow me to return recycleview but not the whole view which only return recycleview on the fragment.

This is my code in onCreateView method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    posts = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=9; i>=0; i--){
        posts.add(new Post("Testing"+i,"For testing","https://picsum.photos/600/300?random?"+i));
    }


    recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getContext());
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);
    pa = new PostAdapter(posts, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(pa);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return recyclerView;
}
```

This is how i do while i try to return whole view

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    posts = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=9; i>=0; i--){
        posts.add(new Post("Testing"+i,"For testing","https://picsum.photos/600/300?random?"+i));
    }

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.strView);
    LinearLayoutManager lim = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lim);
    pa = new PostAdapter(posts, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(pa);


    return view;
}
```

Here is the xml file

```
<FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/strView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addStrBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_create_black_18dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

Logcat while try to return view

```
06-20 20:53:57.733 4990-4990/com.example.cheejin.fyp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cheejin.fyp, PID: 4990
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cheejin.fyp/com.example.cheejin.fyp.HomePage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.example.cheejin.fyp.ChatFragment.onCreateView(ChatFragment.java:56)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3255)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3205)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.example.cheejin.fyp.ChatFragment.onCreateView(ChatFragment.java:56) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3255) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3205) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.example.cheejin.fyp.ChatFragment.onCreateView(ChatFragment.java:56) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3255) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3205) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
    at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawabl
```

Comment: return type is `view` so it should let you return the whole view. What's the error?

Comment: While i try to return view instead just of the recyclerview, it will crush during demo in simulator. However, there is not any coding error.

Comment: Please post logcat.

Comment: Added on top. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution....

Refer to this link
https://blog.csdn.net/Sean_css/article/details/68592412

Just have to change 
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
to
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the layout XML at all. You need to inflate the layout from XML and then find the RecyclerView in that layout.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

    RecyclerView postList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.strView);

    // initialize the recyclerview here like you have above with the layoutmanager and adapter

    return rootView;
}
```

They you can add things like a floating action button, or any other views you want in the layout by writing them in the XML file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply.
i tried to use this method before, but the app crush while demo.

Comment: There is a problem inflating your fab `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` Have you included the design support library in your gradle file? Some attributes you are using are API 21+ are you at API 21 or above? Are the resources you reference all valid?

Comment: I using

compileSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

is there any problem with this?

Comment: I found the solution....

Refer to this link
https://blog.csdn.net/Sean_css/article/details/68592412

Thanks for the help